# Swift switch conditional number & tag of rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView row population code in Swift as follows. The problem is in the second section, row number 2 is conditionally present. If flag is false, then all the subsequent rows shift one cell up, so row 3 becomes row 2. I am wondering if it is possible to specify this conveniently in Swift switch statement, other than from the brute force method where I write 2 switch statements based on flag true or false?

```
    switch indexPath.section {
        
    case 0:
        cell.leftLabel.text = "Row 0";
      
    case 1:
        
        switch indexPath.row {
            
        case 0:
            cell.leftLabel.text = "Setting1"
           
            
        case 1:
            cell.leftLabel.text = "Setting2"
            
            
        case 2:
           /* Conditionally present row */
            if flag {
              cell.leftLabel.text = "Setting3"
             }
            
        case 3:
            cell.leftLabel.text = "Setting4"
           
         ...

      }
```

Comment: Can't you have an array, and add/remove the element at the flag position? How many elements do you have in total?

Comment: Yes, it was much better to make an array of settings enum and manage it. More convenient than hardcoding. Now I can switch on enum type than indexpath.row

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure about the whole use case but here are some improvements that you can do to make this thing easier with `switch case`.

- Firstly, you could use tuple based `switch` for `row` and `section` both at the same time.
- Secondly, use boolean operator together with the cases, which makes this whole comparison more approachable and removes your nesting if / else and casing structures.

Something like this would help you further,

```
switch (indexPath.section, indexPath.row) {
    case (0, _):
    cell.leftLabel.text = "Row 0"      
    case (1, 0):
        cell.leftLabel.text = "Setting1"                       
    case (1, 1):
        cell.leftLabel.text = "Setting2"                        
    case (1, 2) where flag:
          cell.leftLabel.text = "Setting3"
    case (1, 2): // no flag here
        cell.leftLabel.text = "Setting3 without flag"        
    case (1, 3):
        cell.leftLabel.text = "Setting4"
        
     ...   
}
```